# How do you make the box extend all the way till the end if when you hover

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to get the box to extend all the to the end on both sides when i hover with things like flex but it wont work.
Ps i know i have the display block in there

```css
#mainNav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 0px 500px 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#mainNav li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainNav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(121, 184, 19);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 65px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(196, 107, 5);
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.secondUl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondUl li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#mainNav li:hover .secondUl>li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carrot Shops nere me</a>
      <ul class="secondUl">
        <li><a href="#">Walmart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Target</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Costco</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
      <ul class="secondUl">
        <li><a href="#">Biggest Carrot ever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Biggest carrot farm ever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Most carrots ate in 1 serveing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps. Please *let me know* if you had wanted this.

```css
#mainNav ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 0px 500px 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#mainNav li {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainNav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(121, 184, 19);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 65px;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(196, 107, 5);
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.secondUl {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondUl li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

#mainNav li:hover .secondUl>li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Carrot Shops nere me</a>
      <ul class="secondUl">
        <li><a href="#">Walmart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Target</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Costco</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a>
      <ul class="secondUl">
        <li><a href="#">Biggest Carrot ever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Biggest carrot farm ever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Most carrots ate in 1 serveing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: So i was tying to make it so like when you hover over the "more"  the little boxes under neath would extend to all the way over to the sides

Comment: @Adamfire, if it helped you, please upvote it an mark it as answer.So that others could refer it later